# how to redirect different urls to a single login

Tags: c#

In my asp.net website, I have an **sms panel**. When some one sign up in my website and create a user account,they can sent sms with some charges. If they want a **reseller account**, they can request for a reseller account.For resellers, I give another url of my website.They can have users or resellers under their account. Reseller account is approved for only 3 level in the chain. I can approve many resellers under my administration.So I need **several URL** to assigned  to each reseller.But all these **urls** are directed to same website.

Is there any way to direct many URL to a single website?

Comment: What type of project is this? Webforms? MVC? Are you using windows authentication or Forms authentication?

Comment: Give examples of this urls please.

Comment: Show your works. People can't read your mind..

Comment: Does the **real** URL (e.g. .../login/username) lead to an actual page and you're just redirecting them momentarily? **Is this an ASP.NET Web Forms or MVC application?**

Comment: if it's pointing to same url then why u r assigning different url to all.

Comment: @Asha - Why? If the login page is the same despite the user role cannot imagine why you have to use different URL's

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into forms authentication

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

It setups up one login page.  Every page redirects to the same login page if the user hasn't been authenticated yet.  Then once authenticated, it goes back to the page they tried to access first.